# Help me with this COUNT query for a php file

Tags: count

$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Security WHERE ips=$currentip';

How do i get this to count the $currentip values that i make the variable equal to.

Answer (score 3):

assuming you're using the [mysqli][1] function set:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM Security WHERE ips=$currentip';
$response=$mysqli->query($query);
$row=$response->fetch_assoc();
$count=$row['num'];
```

It would be preferable to clean $currentip. Or even better to use a prepared statement.
[1]: https://www.php.net/mysqli

Comment: You really should use prepared statements. Trying to cleanup SQL parameters is a bad smell. It might be especially important with a table like `security` :)